# Spring Autowiring "forgot" about dependency

Tags: java, spring

I wanted to play around with the different types of bean scopes. So I wrote a test environment which should generate a random number so I could see if a bean had changed. My test setup does not work and I can not explain what I found out.

I'm using Spring Boot 2.13 with the Spring Framework 5.15.

Following setup:

*Main class:*

```
package domain.webcreator;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class WebcreatorApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebcreatorApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

*Beans class:*

```
package domain.webcreator;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import java.util.Random;

@Configuration
public class Beans {
    @Bean
    public Random randomGenerator() {
        return new Random();
    }
}
```

*Scoper class:*

```
package domain.webcreator;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Random;

@Service
@Scope("singleton")
public class Scoper {
    private Random rand;

    public Scoper(Random rand) {
        this.rand = rand;
    }

    public int getNumber(int max) {
        return rand.nextInt(max);
    }
}
```

*Index Controller*

```
package domain.webcreator.controller;

import domain.webcreator.Scoper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class IndexController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    @ResponseBody
    @Autowired
    public String indexAction(Scoper scoper) {
        return String.valueOf(scoper.getNumber(50));
    }
}
```

My problem is, that I get an NPE while calling *scoper.getNumber(50)*.
This is strange because when debugging, a Random bean is generated and passed to the scoper constructor.
Later on, in the controller, the rand property is null.
[image: Debugging into Scoper bean creation]
[image: Debugging into Index controller, inspecting created Scoper bean]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to apply `@Autowired` to a random method, which isn't how Spring works. Controller method parameters are for information specific to that HTTP request, not general dependencies, and so Spring is trying to create a new `Scoper` that is associated with the request--but it doesn't have any incoming values in the request to fill in. (I'm actually surprised you're not getting an error about no default constructor.)

Instead, pass your `Scoper` in a constructor.

```
@RestController
public class IndexController {
    private final Scoper scoper;

    public IndexController(Scoper scoper) {
        this.scoper = scoper;
    }

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String indexAction(Scoper scoper) {
        return String.valueOf(scoper.getNumber(50));
    }
}
```

A couple of notes:

- Singleton scope is the default, and there's no need to specify it.
- `@RestController` is preferable to repeating `@ResponseBody` unless you have a mixed controller class.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful. I read about it some time ago but I could not remember it, Feeling a little stupid now.
If others stumble upon this, here you can find supported @Controller method arguments: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.5.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-methods